# For semantic segmentation how to perform data augmentation in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformation, torchvision

I am using PyTorch for semantic segmentation, But I am facing a problem, because I am use **images**, and their **labels**. I want to perform data augmentation such as RandomHorizontalFlip, and RandomCrop, etc.

Here is my code, please check and let me know, how I can embed the following operations in the provided code.

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

class ToTensor(object):
    def __call__(self, sample):
        image, label = sample['image'], sample['label']
        return {'image': F.to_tensor(image), 'label': F.to_tensor(label)}

my_transform = transforms.Compose([ ToTensor() ])

dataset = Mydataset(image_dir, label_dir, transform = my_transform)

# Print dataset output
dataset[1]
```

## Output

```
{'image': tensor([[[0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          ...,
          [0.0902, 0.0902, 0.0902,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0745, 0.0745, 0.0745,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824]],
 
         [[0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          ...,
          [0.0902, 0.0902, 0.0902,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0745, 0.0745, 0.0745,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824]],
 
         [[0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          ...,
          [0.0902, 0.0902, 0.0902,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0745, 0.0745, 0.0745,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824]]]),
 'label': tensor([[[0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          ...,
          [0.0902, 0.0902, 0.0902,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824],
          [0.0745, 0.0745, 0.0745,  ..., 0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824]]])}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use transforms.Compose() method for combining different transforms. For ex:

```
my_transforms = transforms.Compose([  
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(20),
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),
    transforms.RandomCrop((512, 512)),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.2, saturation=0.2, contrast=0.2),
    transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
dataset = Mydataset(image_dir, label_dir, transform = my_transforms)
```

Comment: But i want my ToTensor() return {'image': F.to_tensor(image), 'label': F.to_tensor(label)}

Comment: I know its quite late but did you found the solution @Ahmediqbal